# Bootstrap navbar not functioning properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm trying to create a bootstrap navbar using Jade. This has always worked for me when using vanilla HTML, but it's not giving me the correct result with Jade

```
    nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
    .container-fluid
        .navbar-header
            button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse',
            data-target='#navbar-main')
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
            a.navbar-brand(href='/') Loc8r
        #navbar-main.navbar-collapse.collapse
            ul.nav.navbar-nav
                li
                    a(href='/about/') About
```

I have confirmed that bootstrap is working correctly.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the button doesn't show the 3 icon-bars. In fact, the button shouldn't even be visible when space is available

Comment: Try making the _button_ one line instead of wrapped after **collapse**: `button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbar-main')`.

Comment: Try to nest `container-fluid` inside `.nav`.